# Запрет на прокрутку Text Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, прокрутка, виджет

Мне нужно каким либо способом убрать возможность прокручивать содержимое виджета Text колесом мыши по вертикали, параметр `state=DISABLED` никак не влияет на скролл, как можно заблокировать прокрутку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Под Windows сработал отлов события `<MouseWheel>` и возврат `"break"` обработчиком:

```
text.insert(END, some_text)
text.config(state=DISABLED)
text.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: "break")
```

Под Linux (LinuxMint 20.2, Cinnamon 5.0.5) обработчик события `<MouseWheel>` почему-то не срабатывает (если добавить `print` в обработчик, то ничего не выведет).